# JavaScript Canvas: Pong - Animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm new to HTML 5 + Canvas game dev. Trying to animate the ball in my Pong game. Here's my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/q80bnzjm/2/). Relevant snippets:

Incrementing the velocity of the ball:

```
Ball.prototype.update = function () {
    this.x += this.velocity.x;
    this.y += this.velocity.y;
};
```

Game loop code:

```
function update() {
    ball.update();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

The ball simply sits there. I've Googled it and read several articles, but no luck. I'd appreciate any help in getting the ball to move.

Comment: you're not clearing your canvas for redrawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/q80bnzjm/3/)***

Removed your `render()` function, cause not needed (moved everything into `update()`), you need to

- clear the canvas for redrawing
- "render" again all your updated elements Objects on the canvas on every keyframe (not just on init)

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function init(width, height, bg) {


    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.style.backgroundColor = bg;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);



    function Paddle(x, y, width, height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.velocity = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        };
    }

    Paddle.prototype.render = function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(2, 149, 212)';
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };

    function Player() {
        this.paddle = new Paddle(485, canvas.height / 2 - 25, 15, 50);
    }

    Player.prototype.render = function () {
        this.paddle.render();
    };

    function AI() {
        this.paddle = new Paddle(0, canvas.height / 2 - 25, 15, 50);
    }

    AI.prototype.render = function () {
        this.paddle.render();
    };

    function Ball(x, y, radius) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.velocity = {
            x: 2,
            y: 2
        };
    }

    Ball.prototype.render = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(80, 80, 80)';
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fill();
    };

    Ball.prototype.update = function () {
        this.x += this.velocity.x;
        this.y += this.velocity.y;
    };

    window.player = new Player();
    window.computer = new AI();
    window.ball = new Ball(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 10);

}

function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    player.render();
    computer.render();
    ball.update();
    ball.render();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function main() {
    init(500, 250, '#EEE');
    update();
}

main();
```

Comment: Instead of `clearRect`, you could do `canvas.width = canvas.width`. I've heard it's faster, but maybe it's just easier to remember, or shorter, I don't remember... Maybe it's bad practice, sorry.

Comment: clearRect is significantly quicker and setting the canvas width to itself has an additional side effect: it clears all canvas state.

Comment: I use a small 1 pixel image (or a few pixels if I want a gradient) that I create in code to clear the canvas with a `drawImage(background,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);` which is just as fast as clearRect if not faster, plus gives greater control of the background. Handy to have a nice smoothed gradient rather than a flat colour for not extra GPU time.

Comment: AFAIK a fast way to clear canvas would be clear only the PX that need to be cleared and those are all the old moving elements positions+size.

Comment: When drawing a few balls moving around not any kind of optimisation is required. Just write clean code.